# Is it possible to "unpair" a Bluetooth device in Cocoa/ObjC?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth, iobluetooth

I've paired an `IOBluetoothDevice` in my Mac/Cocoa app and would like to "unpair" it programmatically.  That is, I would like to remove the device from the left pane of the Bluetooth section of System Preferences.

I've seen `[IOBluetoothDevice removeFromFavorites]`, but that just removes the heart icon next to the "Favorite" attribute of the device -- the device is still listed in the left pane.

Is this possible through Cocoa?

[image: Bluetooth Section of System Preferences]

*In the above picture, I would like to programmatically remove "Apple Mighty Mouse" from the left pane.*

Comment: do you want to remove the same in mac or ios app??

Comment: @hussainShabbir The tags should tell you that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paired devices are a part of System Preferences.

You can find the file with the bluetooth preferences in `/Library/Preferences`, its name is `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`.

[image: com.apple.Bluetooth.plist]

However, you cannot edit the file directly. You should use `SCPreferences` class from `System Configuration` framework.

Note the API for accessing/modifying system preferences is pretty low level.

EDIT: The following code works if run in superuser mode. I am not a Mac OS developer myself but it should be possible to init it with an `AuthorizationRef` and run it with user mode (the user will confirm access to system configuration).

```
SCPreferencesRef prefs = SCPreferencesCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             CFSTR("Test"),
                                             CFSTR("/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist"));

const CFStringRef PAIRED_DEVICES_KEY = CFSTR("PairedDevices");

NSArray *pairedDevices = (__bridge NSArray *) SCPreferencesGetValue(prefs, PAIRED_DEVICES_KEY);

NSLog(@"Paired devices: %@", pairedDevices);

NSString *deviceToRemove = @"e4-32-cb-da-ca-2f";        

NSMutableArray *newPairedDevices = [pairedDevices mutableCopy];
[newPairedDevices removeObject:deviceToRemove];

Boolean valueSet = SCPreferencesSetValue(prefs, PAIRED_DEVICES_KEY, (__bridge CFPropertyListRef) [NSArray arrayWithArray:newPairedDevices]);

NSLog(@"Value set: %@", (valueSet) ? @"YES" : @"NO");

if (!valueSet) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", SCCopyLastError());
}

Boolean saved = SCPreferencesCommitChanges(prefs);

if (!saved) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", SCCopyLastError());
}

NSLog(@"Saved: %@", (saved) ? @"YES" : @"NO");

CFRelease(prefs);
```

Comment: everything is working great until `SCPreferencesCommitChanges` where I get a `Error Domain=com.apple.SystemConfiguration Code=1002 "Invalid argument" UserInfo={NSDescription=Invalid argument}`. Would you happen to know why this could be going on? Thank you!

Comment: @MikeJSChoi Did you try exactly this code or are you rewriting to Swift?

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite this into Swift! Here's a link to my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764449/modify-scpreferences-persistent-storage-invalid-argument