# Modify SCPreferences persistent storage: Invalid Argument

Tags: swift, cocoa, authorization, sudo, cfpreferences

Currently trying to modify `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` in order to programmatically remove Bluetooth devices and running into an error.

First of all, when `SCPreferencesSetValue` is called, System Configuration says

> Error Domain=com.apple.SystemConfiguration Code=0 "Success!" UserInfo={NSDescription=Success!}

However, when I try to `SCPreferencesCommitChanges`, the framework tells me

> Error Domain=com.apple.SystemConfiguration Code=1002 "Invalid argument" UserInfo={NSDescription=Invalid argument}

I don't understand how setting a value succeeds but committing a value with a regular preferences object fails... Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

```
var authItem = AuthorizationItem(name: kAuthorizationRuleIsAdmin, valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
var authRights = AuthorizationRights(count: 1, items: &authItem)
let flags : AuthorizationFlags = [.interactionAllowed, .extendRights, .preAuthorize, .extendRights]
let osStatus = AuthorizationCopyRights(self.authRef!, &authRights, nil, flags, nil)

let preferences = SCPreferencesCreateWithAuthorization(kCFAllocatorDefault, "defaults" as CFString, "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist" as CFString, authRef)        

if !(SCPreferencesSetValue(preferences!, "PairedDevices" as CFString, paired as CFPropertyList)) {
    return false
}

print("Set Value: \(SCCopyLastError())")

let ok = SCPreferencesCommitChanges(preferences!)
if !ok {
    print("Commit Changes: \(SCCopyLastError())")
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `paired` should be a `NSArray` of strings, not a `CFPropertyList`.

Comment: @Sulthan Just tried it and I'm getting the same error :(

Comment: The solution was to use `Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` instead of `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`; notice the lack of `/` in the beginning of the path. However, the Bluetooth Device is still not removed successfully even though the `PairedDevice` key of the `.plist` is successfully updated.

Comment: With `Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` (relative path) your actually committing (writing) to `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`, not `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`

Comment: @NoHalfBits ah makes sense. Is there a way to write it to the actual .plist file instead with the code above?

Comment: The CFPreferences-API does this when called with an applicationID of `"com.apple.Bluetooth.plist"` and `kCFPreferencesAnyUser` / `kCFPreferencesAnyHost` _from a process that runs with root privileges_. And the 'official way' to run something with root privileges is to implement it as a privileged helper tool.